# Toggling div position:fixed sometimes causes scrolling bug

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a horizontal menu that I've implemented with CSS and HTML5. I have code to add a "fixed" class to "lock" the menu to the top of the screen when the user scrolls past it:

```
$(function(){
        // number of pixels before "locking" menu is the distance between the menu and the top of the page
        var numScroll = $("#mainMenu").offset().top;

        // toggle "fixed" class depending on scroll position, so that when menu is passed it gets locked to top of screen
        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > numScroll) {
                // add fixed class and set "left" property dynamically to properly center the menu
                $('#mainMenu').addClass('fixed').css('left', function(){
                    return ($(window).width()-$(this).width())/2;
                });
            } else {
                $('#mainMenu').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the "fixed" class css code:

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    display:table;
    padding:0;
    /* Set high z-index so that it appears on top of anything on the page when scrolling */
    z-index: 99;
}
```

This works well. The problem is that in some cases, which seems to depend on the window/content height, the page "locks" just before the bottom and doesn't let you scroll the last bit to the end of the page. When you try to scroll the last bit it sort of bounces back up. I'm not sure what is causing this or how to avoid it.

(You can see a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849927/locking-menu-on-scroll-slightly-off) for more detailed code if necessary)

**Update:** [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xt3yf0zb/16/) with all the code, but I can't seem to replicate the scroll issue that's showing up on our website.

**Update 2:** 
I actually managed to replicate it [in this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xt3yf0zb/17/), by removing some of the empty space. You may have to play around with the size of the output window, but it seems to appear when the lowest scrolling point would *just* cause the menu to snap to the top.

Comment: I'd probably just recommend using the 'sticky.js' plugin.  Save you having to write essentially the same functionality from scratch.

Comment: Is this part, `var numScroll = 20;`, from the other question still in your code? ... and if so, could it be those `20px` you see it bounce back up?

Comment: @LGSon - no I changed the numScroll to be dynamic

Comment: @Brett84c - looks cool, but would prefer to stick to our own code for now

Comment: I feel ya.  I prefer to build most everything in my apps from scratch just because I think it makes me a better developer.  If it's something that I just don't have the time to custom build or already generally know how to do it, then I'll usually use a plugin or library.  Btw, do you have a Fiddle or Codepen for this?  I could probably help you find a solution if you can get all the necessary code in one.

Comment: @Brett84c - added a fiddle but I can't seem to replicate the issue. Even on our site, it only shows up occasionally depending on page / browser height and possibly screen resolution

Comment: Figured out the problem.  Let me know if my answer helps @froadie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:  I misconstrued the original problem so I've update my answer to just show how i'd handle making a sticky header that triggers when scrolling past it.

My recommendation:  Add an empty div element (gave it the ID 'menuLocator' in my example) directly before the menu then check that element's offset to know when to apply and remove the 'fixed' class to the menu.  Because that div remains statically placed on the page where the menu HTML is, your scroll event can now tell where the menu is supposed to be and to apply the 'fixed' class if you scroll beyond that.

Here's my solution.  I know I didn't use the exact same HTML or CSS, it should just give you a general idea of one way of doing a sticky header.

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function(e){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#menuLocator').offset().top) {
    $('.horizontalMenu').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.horizontalMenu').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
#filler {
  height:2000px;
  background:lightgray;
}
.horizontalMenu {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.menuInner {
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 3px black;
  background:white;
}
.menuInner ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.menuInner li {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1%;
}
.menuInner li:hover {
  background:gray;
}
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Space Filler</h2>
<h3>More Space Filler</h3>
<div id="menuLocator"></div>
<div class='horizontalMenu'>
  <div class="menuInner">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu 1</li>
      <li>Menu 2</li>
      <li>Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="filler">
  <h4>Random Page Content</h4>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<p>Bottom of Page</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! A coworker actually just noticed the issue and suggested a filler to take the place of the menu. Here's his fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bbrwmdjp/4/ I also thought of adding code to only apply the "fixed" class when scroll direction is down and only remove it when scroll direction is up. I'm going to accept your answer for identifying the issue which I've been struggling with for a while!

Comment: I modified the CSS a little to be more responsive.  The 'menuInner' element is 80% of the full width of the page based on it's parent 'horizontalMenu'.  I apply `margin:0 auto` to center the menu.  The <li> elements widths are set to roughly equally fill the 'menuInner' element based on percentages.  I try to avoid using Javascript for CSS styling if possible unless my solution cannot be solved through CSS styles by applying a class.

Comment: Actually, I think your explanation may be slightly off - it only determines the offset from the menu once on page load. If it was determining it dynamically then we would have this issue always, not just in some cases depending on page height. The issue actually seems to be that the height of the menu is being removed from the page when it's fixed so that window.scrollTop goes back down under "numScroll". Then it removes the fixed class and the menu gets added back in to the page and it goes back over again... and keeps toggling.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you look in my code, I eliminated the 'numScroll' variable and just put it's value selector directly in the 'if' statement:  `$('#menuLocator').offset().top`.  The code isn't getting the offset from the menu at all, it's getting it from the "menuLocator" element, which is located at the exact same position in the HTML as the 'horizontalMenu'.  Whenever you scroll above the 'menuLocator', the 'fixed' class is removed from 'horizontalMenu', when you scroll below, it applies the 'flxed' class which takes it out of it's position in the HTML.

Comment: Your solution seems correct - I just meant that your explanation of the issue in your first paragraph is not correct.

Comment: How?  It explains exactly what was causing your problem.  To put it more simply, you were checking and then changing the location of the menu on the page every time the scroll event happened.  When you passed beyond the menu element, the 'fixed' CSS took over.  When that took over, the offset changed to '0' because of the `top:0` property on the 'fixed' class.  This caused the 'if else' blocks to toggle.  You were changing the location on the page then checking the location and changing it back on every scroll.  Not sure how else to explain it.  My code proves what i'm saying.

Comment: I think the problem was not that the offset changed to 0 - it didn't matter if the offset changed because I was only determining the offset once on page load and saving it in numScroll. In the bind callback in the if/else statement I was not dynamically checking the offset. The problem actually seems to be that the menu gets removed from the page and so the scrollTop goes down by the height of the menu and then `$(window).scrollTop() > numScroll` evaluates to false again.

Comment: I tried implementing your method in the fiddle and I am still getting the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/xt3yf0zb/18/ . (Presumably because it's not the offset location that's the problem, it's the fact that as you pass the menu the scrollTop loses the height of the menu and falls back under the offset. That's why the issue only happens in particular cases when you don't actually fully pass the menu.) I think I'm going to go with the solution in this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/bbrwmdjp/4

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I thought you were getting the 'numScroll' value within the scroll function.  My bad for not catching that.  That makes sense.  The menu was getting taken out of the normal HTML flow, causing the scroll bar to shrink, changing the scrollTop() value for the window.  Anywho, feel free to use my code.  I'd recommend trying to implement a similar percentage-based sizing technique for your menu if you can find a way to adapt your HTML and CSS.  Will make your page more responsive.  I find it's best to avoid styling with Javascript unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same issue and thanks to your post I was able to find help, I found out that this jumping behavior happens at certain content heights exactly as you stated,

The reason it keeps jumping is at certain content height after the header is docked to the top, the pageYOffset reading is returning unexpected value(value i got is less than what I expected by the amount of anchor offset, not sure why is this happening) in a way that misses up the whole logic and therefore menu keeps docking and undocking causing a flickering like behavior

I was able to by pass it with altering my code to add menu locator offset to the scroll Position in case the "#ribbonBarSection"/menu has been already docked

1- I use this method to return whether my menu "#ribbonBarSection" should be docked to the top or displayed normally

```
hasPassedTopAnchor(hasBeenDocked: boolean): boolean {
    const anchor = document.getElementById('menuLocator');
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset ;
    let adjusted = hasBeenDocked ? anchor.offsetTop : 0;
    return (scrollPosition + adjusted) > anchor.offsetTop;
  }
```

2- I added an extra div "#adjustedScrollHeight" just before my footer.

3- I called the following custom function from two places, when document loads  and @the window resize event

the custom function will alter a div height to add extra vertical scrolling height so the jumping behavior is mitigated

```
  private onResize() {
    document.getElementById('adjustedScrollHeight').style.height = '0';
    this.adjustScrollHeight();
  }

  private adjustScrollHeight() {
    const verticalScrollDiff = document.documentElement.offsetHeight
      - document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    const anchorTop = document.getElementById('menuLocator').offsetTop;
    const ribbonBarOffsetTop = document.getElementById('ribbonBarSection').offsetTop;
    const upperScrollBoundary = ribbonBarOffsetTop + anchorTop + 1;

    if (verticalScrollDiff <= ribbonBarOffsetTop) {
      return;
    }

    if (verticalScrollDiff > upperScrollBoundary) {
      return;
    }

    //IE requires extra pixel for scrolling 
    const adjustedscrollHeight = ((upperScrollBoundary + 1) - verticalScrollDiff) + 1;
    document.getElementById('adjustedScrollHeight').style.height = adjustedscrollHeight + 'px';}
```

Comment: Although I didn't use this exact code, thanks to it I understood the problem was the change of height of the document.  When I was in top of the page, my menu had an height of 102px. When I scrolled down, I changed its height to 60px, so the vertical scroll missed 42px, and the window became crazy going up and down by itself. The solution was, as in this answer, adding a div at footer: when my menu turns to 60px, I give thos 42px to this extra div's height. Et voilà! Problem solved. Thank you very much, +1

Answer (score 0):

I found the causing issue in my case my html was like

```
<nav>some content </nav>
```

I replaced nav tag with a div and voila scrolling worked fine !! it must be related to bootstrap thing, I am assuming that the nav tag was expecting some css classes which were not provided